# FontAwesome with Python

Tags: python, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the Font Awesome icon set for python but I can't manage to make it work.
I'm following all the instructions I found on https://pypi.org/project/fontawesome/ but somehow the end result is not what expected.
If I run those 2 simple lines I end up with some kind of indian or arabic symbol.

```
import fontawesome as fa  
print(fa.icons['thumbs-up'])
```

Does anyone here have experience with this module?

Thanks

Comment: Can your terminal display the necessary font?

Comment: Both from terminal or a tkinter Label comes out the same strange symbol

Answer (score 1):

> 28. pip3 install fontawesome
> 29. sudo apt-get update -y
> 30. sudo apt-get install -y fonts-font-awesome
> 31. pip3 install pypandoc
> 32. pip3 install py-pandoc
> 33. Downloading from: https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/#files then python3.6 setup.py build and python3.6 setup.py install
> 34. Downloading fontawesome from https://pypi.org/project/fontawesome/ then python3.6 setup.py build and python3.6 setup.py install

I think 31,32 it's not necessary