# Python3.6 use font awesome icons

Tags: python, font-awesome

I am searching how can i use font-awesome icons to a Tkinter python application.

Here is what i tried:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/tree?style=solid

```
pip3 install fontawesome

Python 3.6.9 (default, May 23 2020, 00:01:58) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fontawesome as fa
>>> print(fa.icons['tree'])

>>>
```

I know that i must download icons - map (i do it in the past) but i don't find now how.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Same question before 26 days: [FontAwesome with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462679/fontawesome-with-python)

Comment: The character you see has been encoded in your python console, it doesn't mean that it's not correct, just your console is unable to render it properly... I guess!

Comment: I agree with Alireza, try printing to a file.

Comment: I tried to show it in a tkinter menu. I saw a blank rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see actual icons on your shell you need to install fontawesome's font on your computer and configure your terminal emulator to use this font.

Fontawesome the font is a font, but instead of just letters it also got icons.

`fontawesome` the python library is just dictionary with the icon's name as key and the character as value. But you can see the actual caractere only if you install Fontawesome the font.

Comment: Instruction how can i do this (Ubuntu 20.04) please?

Comment: I follow this instructions: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/fonts-font-awesome